# Trouble inserting data using BatchInsert in Coredata

Tags: swift, macos, core-data

I am using the below code to batch-insert large volumes of data in core data. The objects are created, however, the data is missing. The dictionary array has the correct data when inserting, but when I retrieve the data I see nil and incorrect data displayed as shown in the sample image.

```
let appDelegate = await NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
let batchInsert = NSBatchInsertRequest(entityName: entityName.rawValue, objects: data)
let result = try? context.execute(batchInsert) as? NSBatchInsertResult
```

Inconsistent output with nil

[image: Data errors]

The dictionary data passed in to create the batch insert data

[image: Dictionary Sample]

Comment: It's hard to tell. You seem to have entered multiple times "Country 0"? Try to identify which dict fails, and put them clearly in text here, in image it's harder.

Comment: Instead of using the optional try?, actually try/catch and then you should see an error.

Comment: @Larme Thank you for your response. I have validated the dictionary data, for testing I have used a string concatenated with the counter. So the expected output should be Country 0 and the next one should be country 1 and so on...

Comment: Thank you for your response @MartinM. I have used do-catch, however, the code is not throwing any error.

Comment: How do you merge that context into the main context? Please provide a minimum reproducible example. Out of that few lines of code it is hard to tell what is wrong, it is too incomplete.

Comment: Thanks @MartinM Seems like that is the piece I am missing, I am learning this concept and will try to research how to merge it into the main context. Would appreciate it if you have any guidance on who to find help or a code snippet.

Comment: @MartinM I was trying to refer to this document https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/loading_and_displaying_a_large_data_feed

Comment: Are you aware that a batch insert inserts the objects into the persistent store, but not in the context that you use to retrieve the objects, unless you have set the property automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent to true?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner Thank you for your help, I tried that and it worked. Was able to insert and retrieve records. Now, will do research on how to insert data with relationships. Thanks again!